# Unsatisfied Dependency in Quarkus

Tags: dependency-injection, javabeans, cdi, quarkus, openapi-generator

i have got a Rest Controller which was genereated with Openapi (kotlin client), thus meaning, that i am not allowed to change the code inside the controller.

I have got another class which injects the generated Controller
`class ProductsService @inject constructor (val productsController: ProductControllerApi)`  <-- ProducControllerApi is generated

But this causes: Unsatisfied dependency for type ProductControllerApi and qualifiers [@Default]

One Solution is to annotate the generated class with @ApplicationScoped, but this doesnt really solve the problem because it is a generated class so all changes will be lost everytime the class gets generated

Does anybody have an idea?

Edit:
It works with a producer method:

```
    @Producer
fun getProductController(): ProductControllerApi{
return ProductControllerApi
}
```

Comment: Have you tried adding `@RestClient` to the constructor parameter?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. Unfortunately, it doesnt work: Unsatisfied dependency for type ProductControllerApi and qualifiers [@RestClient]

Comment: When your rest controller is not eligible for injection, as it's not annotated as a bean, you can just add a producer method in a suitable place. See https://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/5.0.0.Final/en-US/html_single/#_producer_methods